# How do you maintain CSS layout when adding content (ASP.NET)

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a page in ASP.NET as follows.

JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/nyrUp/

HTML

```
    <div class="mainContainer">
        <div>
            <div class="topLeft">
                <% =DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()%>
            </div>
            <div class="topRight">
                foo
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="bottomLeft">
                foo
            </div>
            <div class="bottomRight">
                foo
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="underneath">
            foo
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.mainContainer {
}
.topLeft {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;    
}

.topRight {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: orange;
}

.bottomLeft {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.bottomRight {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}

.underneath {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

This works fine, until you add content to any div, at which point the layout is broken

JSFIDDLE showing broken layout: http://jsfiddle.net/4gbP8/

How do I maintain this layout when content is added please?

i.e.[image]

Comment: You have some good answers below. I'll add some good resources for reading that talk about "clearfix": [PositionIsEverything.com](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html), [Clearfix Micro](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to contain them by placing a container on the blank div, called top. I think if I understand correctly you want each box to fill the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/4gbP8/2/
CSS ADD

```
.top {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;

 }
```

HTML

```
       <div class="top">
            <div class="topLeft">
                <p>123</p>
                <p>123</p>
                <p>123</p>
                <p>123</p>
            </div>
            <div class="topRight">
                foo
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Although I don't think you need the height:100% in the CSS. See http://jsfiddle.net/pYH5G/

Comment: Yah the height was an attempt to get the full width and height, which did not occur, but there is a way to do this so your site is responsive, if responsive (Should be) is a big issue.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if you are able to update the HTML but I have a solution If you can add in a new class.

I added a class called `clear` which help to push down the different levels and gives them a bit more structure.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4gbP8/1/)**

**CSS**

```
.clear{clear:both;}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="mainContainer">
            <div class="clear">
                <div class="topLeft">
                    <p>123</p>
                    <p>123</p>
                    <p>123</p>
                    <p>123</p>
                </div>
                <div class="topRight">
                    foo
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
                <div class="bottomLeft">
                    foo
                </div>
                <div class="bottomRight">
                    foo
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="underneath clear">
                foo
            </div>
        </div>
```

Let me know if it helps or I could tweek something to make it work better for yourself

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues

In order to keep the column distribution you must clear the floats

In order to kept the backgrounds you must use negative margins "equ" exaggerated paddings

You will get this

(
See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/mcGny/) with demo and full coding )

[image]

You must include wrapers for each pair of floating elements and some css for the negative margin trick
Markup should be as follows

```
<div class="mainContainer">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="topLeft">
                    <p>123</p>
                    <p>123</p>
                    <p>123</p>
                    <p>123</p>
                </div>
                <div class="topRight">
                    foo
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="bottomLeft">
                    foo
                </div>
                <div class="bottomRight">
                    <p>123</p>
                    <p>123</p>
                    <p>123</p>
                    <p>123</p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="underneath clear">
                foo
            </div>
        </div>
```

Each floating div should include

```
{
   ...
    padding-bottom:2000px;
    margin-bottom:-2000px;
...
}
```

The ....left divs should include

```
{
  ...
  clear:left;
...
}
```

And the wraper to be included for each pair of floating divs should be

```
.wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The table/table-cell display properties can do what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/4gbP8/3/

```
.mainContainer {
}

.mainContainer > div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.topLeft {
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;    
}

.topRight {
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: orange;
}

.bottomLeft {
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.bottomRight {
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: green;
}

.underneath {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

If the content needs to reflow for narrow devices, hide the display properties behind a media query targeting wider devices.